# [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a Glue script which is supposed to write its result in a Redshift table in a for loop.

After many hours of processing it raises this exception:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o11362.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection refused.
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Redshift clusters have a [maintenance window](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html#rs-maintenance-windows) in which they are re-booted. This event of course causes the Glue Job to fail when attempting to write to a table of that cluster.

May be useful to reschedule the maintenance window https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-clusters-console.html

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur for many reasons. I'm sure after a few google searches you've found that the most common cause of this is improper security group settings for your cluster (make sure your inbound settings are correct).

I would suggest that you make sure you're able to create a connection for even a short period of time before you try this longer process. If you are able to do so, then I bet the issue is that your connection is closing out after a timeout (since your process is so long). To solve this, you should look into **connection pooling**, which involves creating an instance of a connection and constantly checking to ensure it is still alive, thus allowing a process to continuously use the cluster connection.